# Hydrogen atom as a canonical ensemble

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

A cylinder of hydrogen gas is maintained at a temperature T. I want to find the probability of a single H atom to be in a certain state of energy E using the canonical ensemble formulae. The probability of being in a state of energy E is given by $e^{-E/k/T}$. This formula gives me senseless result, since there are infinite energy levels just below $E=0$.

The senseless result is that the probability of H atom being in any state (of energy E) is $0$.

Is the canonical ensemble formula not applicable to this situation? If not, why?

Comment: *What exactly* is the "senseless result" you get? Is it any different from discovering that the probability to detect a particle *at a point* is actually zero (because the wavefunction is a probability density, not a probability)?

Comment: The senseless result is that the probability of H atom being in any state (of energy E) is 0.

Comment: Should I also consider the translational kinetic energy of the H atom to arrive at sensible results?

Comment: Maybe you could find transition probabilities and then take the expectation value? I don't know if this has been done.

Comment: @ACuriousMind This situation really is quite different from what you brought up. In the case of probability distributions over a continuum, a point has measure zero, and you need an interval (with nonzero length) to have nonzero probability. But here, the energy levels are discretely labeled and you would expect nonzero probability to find an atom in any single state. As an illustration of how weird this is, the probability of finding an atom in any of the lowest million energy states is zero—which can't be right.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the thing. The first electronic transition (from the ground-state to the first excited state) requires $\frac{3}{4}(13.6 \,\mathrm{eV}) \approx 10\,\mathrm{eV}$.

The energy available in a collision of two atoms in a equilibrium gas is a few times the thermal energy $k_b T$. For room temperature the thermal energy is about $\frac{1}{40}\,\mathrm{eV}$. For a low temperature gas the atoms all have their electronic configuration in the ground state all the time. (For values of "all" meaning *"you could find a counter example here and there if you waited long enough but it won't actually change the result of any observation you might want to make"*.)

The electronic levels are "frozen out", and only the translational behavior matters.

The temperature dependence of the specific heat of diatomic gases is commonly used as a classroom example of this kind of behavior. At low temperature it is $\frac{3}{2}k_b T$ because only the translational modes are accessible. At slightly higher temperatures the rotational modes start to be activated the the specific heat rises to $\frac{5}{2} k_b T$ (because there are two distinct modes) where it plateaus for a while before the vibrational modes come on-line at still higher temperature and cause the specific heat to climb again to $\frac{7}{2}k_b T$ (two more modes) where it once more becomes more or less constant.

In order to activate the electronic modes even a little you need your gas to have a thermal energy of a few electron-volts corresponding to more than 10,000 kelvin. And once you get to that level ionization becomes possible because the subsequent excitations require less energy.

Answer (score 0):

This paper resolves my doubts to a great extent.

http://www.ifi.unicamp.br/~mtamash/f604_fisest/pra80_032113.pdf

I found this paper when I searched 'Hydrogen atom in a box'. One key idea is that the standard H atom energy spectrum results (as taught in an introductory quantum mechanics course) are not applicable to this problem because, besides the Coulomb potential of the nucleus, there is also the constraint force of the cylinder which renders the standard H-atom results wrong; hence the senseless result when you use the canonical ensemble formula. See the above paper for more details.

Comment: You're over thinking it and misinterpreting that paper. If you could keep the hydrogen in monatomic form (good luck), the the translational behavior would remain decoupled from the electronic degrees of freedom until the temperature is on order of ten thousand kelvin. There simply isn't a way for the bumping around of the atomic motion to excite the electron degrees of freedom when they first excitation is, for instance, 300 times the room temperature thermal energy.  The paper concerns itself with how being in a box affects an isolated atom.

Comment: @dmckee I think the OP is referring to the fact that the hydrogen atom's partition function diverges. (Because there are infinitely many states piled up around the same energy.)

Comment: @knz That the question he's tried to answer here, but it's not the question in the first two sentences of the question. This trick of using one aton as the system and treating the rest of the sample as the bath is an old game.